# How can I create a method that accepts either double or decimal as a parameter type

Tags: c#

I would like this method to be able to handle *decimal?* also.

Is this possible? I dont want to use object as parameter type.

```
    public static string SurroundWithQuotes(double? amount)
    {
        if (amount == null)
        {
            return String.Empty;
        }

        string format = "{0:0,0.00}";
        string formattedNumber = String.Format(format, amount);

        if (amount < 1000)
        {
            return formattedNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            string quote = "\"";
            return quote + formattedNumber + quote;
        }
    }
```

Comment: no you need to add another overload for that.

Comment: `public static string SurroundWithQuotes(double? amount)` and `public static string SurroundWithQuotes(decimal? amount)`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Or you can have a generic method like this:

```
public static string SurroundWithQuotes<T>(T amount)
{
    if (amount == null)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
    string format = "{0:0,0.00}";
    string formattedNumber = String.Format(format, amount);

    decimal amnt = Convert.ToDecimal(amount);

    if (amnt < 1000)
    {
        return formattedNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        string quote = "\"";
        return quote + formattedNumber + quote;
    }
}
```

The constraint is that the type T must be able to be casted to decimal.

Comment: @MoreCoffee Using generics accomplishes nothing here. You may as well just have the method accept an `object` if you're going to go this route.

Comment: The generic type is only because in some future .NET framework we should probably have better type constraints like where `T : CanBeCastedTo decimal`... Just joking, you're right and should use object instead.

Comment: @JLRishe But object has boxing/unboxing which will hurts performance. Generics do not, am I wrong?

Comment: @MoreCoffee The value is going to get boxed into an object when you pass it into `String.Format()` and `Convert.ToDecimal()` so you may as well do it ahead of time and box once instead of twice. Also, a micro-optimization like that wouldn't generally be a good reason to use a generic method instead of one that takes `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Create another method with the same name, but use a decimal parameter.

```
public static string SurroundWithQuotes(decimal? amount)
```

When you call the method with a decimal, it will select the correct one. 
This is called overloading.

Comment: Ok I guess that's the only way. I didn't want to repeat the entire method but oh well

Comment: @MoreCoffee You don't need to repeat the entire method. Please see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can just have your main version of the method accept a `decimal?` and make a one-line overload for `double?`:

```
public static string SurroundWithQuotes(double? amount)
{
    return SurroundWithQuotes((decimal?)amount);
}
```

That will work just fine.